# Class that has nested array properties in typeorm

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, postgresql-9.4

I'm using TypeORM with Postgresql and having trouble creating entity file with nested scheme

The records I would like returned from my database should look like this:

```
[{  
    id: 1,
    name: 'john'
    preferences: {
       colors: ['red', 'white', '#ff5d5d'],
       cars: ['vw', 'bmw']
    }
}]
```

Im having trouble with the `preferences` property.
this is what I tried:

```
@Entity()
export class Person {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;
  
  @Column()
  name: string;

  preferences: {
    @OneToMany(() => Color, c => c)
    colors: Color[]

    @OneToMany(() => Car, c => c)
    cars: Car[]
  }
}    

@Entity()
export class Color {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;
 
  @Column()
  value: string;
}  

@Entity()
export class Car {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;
 
  @Column()
  value: string;
}
```

This does not compile because i cant put the `OneToMany` decorator in a nested property and
also I don't need id for the colors nor the cars.
I only use id because I need it mapped per person.